# angular2 get string in json format on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angular

I'm trying to get the title from json response using a `click` event, I manage to get all the titles when I click on the button, but how can I get specific title depending on the `button` or `a href` the user clicked?

```
modalGetTitle(title) {
    this.http.get('../../xmlConf/dashboard_journey.json')
    .map((res:Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
        if(data) {
            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
            this.oJourney = jsonObj.o.journey;
            this.getJourneyTitle = this.oJourney; 

            for (var i = 0; i < this.getJourneyTitle.length; i++) {
                var element = this.getJourneyTitle[i];
                console.log(element.title);
            }      
        }

    });
};
```

Like
if I click on `<button (click)="modalGetTitle()">Title 1</button>` and I want to render the json response title in a `<span>`, therefore the button is just to trigger the function.

Atm I'm only getting the last item from the response:

```
<a href="javascript:;" (click)="modalGetTitle()" class="float-shadow" *ngIf="journey.journey_url == 'javascript:;' ">{{journey.title}} </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this, if i'm understand your question.

```
<button ng-click="modalGetTitle()"><span id="spanId">Title</span></button>
```

in controller you can define function

```
          $scope.modalGetTitle = function(){
var title = document.getElementById('spanId').innerHTML
             this.http.get('../../xmlConf/dashboard_journey.json')
                .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                .subscribe(data => {
                    if(data) {
                        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                        this.oJourney = jsonObj.o.journey;
                        this.getJourneyTitle = this.oJourney; 

                        for (var i = 0; i < this.getJourneyTitle.length; i++) {

                            var element = this.getJourneyTitle[i];
        if(element == title){
                            console.log(element.title);
        }
                        }      
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: but that will only get me whatever is in the hardcoded scope? I'm planning to show the title in a <span>. Button is just to trigger the function.

Comment: in that case you can in function set title like this

var title = document.getElementById('spanId').innerHTML;

Comment: If statement is not returning anything and I don't think I'll need to do the document get as I can probably just {{ title }} in the view. See my reply to Thierry.

Comment: i am not understand what you want. I am put simple example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jasmin_kurtic/5bL5tfo5/12/), if you can not use, please post what you are doing

Comment: Thanks, though its in angular1 but it gave me the idea and was being blind. My span was outside the scope that's why I couldn't get anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass something as parameter of your method. For example:

```
<button (click)="modalGetTitle('title1')">Title 1</button>
```

Comment: Sorry can you explain this a bit more? button is just to trigger the function and I want to show the json response title in a <span>

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure to understand what you want to do. What will you select the title you want to display from the response payload?

Comment: Yeah sorry I sounded confusing, I have a collection of links (e.g <a href..>JS</a>) with (click) event to trigger the function and get the response with the title of (JS) and show the response in <span> tag.

Comment: my code is only returning me the last item from the json response.

Answer (score 0):

do it like this

```
<button (click)="modalGetTitle(this)">Title 1</button>
function modalGetTitle() {
    alert(objButton.textContent); // this will show "Title 1"
}
```